# Smart cards with PKI certificate. What common issue is to expect?

Tags: certificate, smartcard, pki

I am trying to figure out what kind of issues might overcome when using a smart card for Authentication (Logon by Smart card) and Email encryption.

Additionally, I am not really sure about storing key data on cards. Here are some possible issues and my thoughts, but not sure about them, since the case is new to me:

1. If the smart card is damaged, the only way is to get a new card, which most probably will come with a new certificate stored on it (is this correct?). Is there a need to revoke the certificate of the damaged card?
2. The smart card's certificate is expired, in this case, a new certificate will be issued, but is it required to generate a new key pair (private and public keys) or using ongoing keys is ok? Are there some additional steps required, like importing the new certificate into the smart card?
3. The smart card has been forgotten and the user needs to log on to system, let's say on a Windows Desktop Client. Providing a temporary smart card would be an option or not? If yes, how should be the temp card assigned to the user since he/she needs it to deal with secure emails?

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess, this depends on the PKI. The worst, that can
   happen is, that you receive mails you are no longer able
   to decipher and you have to ask for a resend. The more
   sensitive operation digital signature is safe, since with
   the defective card signatures can no longer be created.
2. Certificates expire mostly, so you are forced to create a new key pair. (While other signed data may also have changed, this is typically not worth to issue a new certificate.)
3. A temporary replacement fixes only a limited number of issues. There should be another way to login, to handle the case of a defective card. For a mission-critical approach the whole application has to be aware of this. When a full-replacement must be possible, this means, that no key pairs are generated on the card (because there frequently is no way to export the private part) and the external storage has to ensure security of the all keys.